# HttpRequestException when trying PutAsync

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm working on a Windows 10 Universal app and I keep getting a **"The HTTP redirect request must be confirmed by the user"** error when I try to do the following:

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response = await http.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(temp));
```

Any ideas on how to handle that?

Comment: Does the code works in Windows 8.1?

Comment: @kiewic Yup it worked in Windows 8.1

Comment: It must be a side effect of UWP projects `EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile` setting. If you compile using Windows 8.1 projects, it should continue working fine in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround to the problem by setting AllowAutoRedirect to false and then making a call to the redirect manually.

```
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        HttpClient http = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response = await http.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(temp));

        url = response.Headers.Location;
        response = await http.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(temp));
```